# jquery to change value of a class element based on other class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html-parsing

I have a page with many same type of divs as below.

```
<div class="post_right" data-icon = "arrow-r">
 <p>Posted at:</p>
 <div class="post_time"> 
  <%= post.created_at.strftime("%I:%M %P") %> 
 </div>
 <div class="post_timer"></div>
</div>
```

I have a jquery script which will read from "post_time" class and update post_timer class by adding a value to it.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".post_timer").each(function(){
    var post_time = $(".post_time").html()
    $(this).html(post_time);
    });     
});
```

But all the "post_timer" class value are getting updated by the first post_time value. Any way I can update the post_timer value based on corresponding "post_time" class value all through the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".post_timer").each(function(){
    var post_time = $(this).prev(".post_time").html();
    $(this).html(post_time);
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `$(".post_time")` of the same index; `.html` will just get the first one otherwise (as you see).

```
var post_time = $(".post_time").eq($(this).index()).html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kVNGN/

Answer (score 1):

Just traverse the DOM to the appropriate element. Since in your example, the `.post_time` element seems to be the previous sibling of the `.post_timer` element, you can use [`.prev` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$(".post_timer").html(function() {
    return $(this).prev().html();
    // or more structure independent: 
    // return $(this).siblings('.post_time').html();
});
```

jQuery has many more [traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).